# c# regexp pattern to <id> .... </id>

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote the following pattern:

```
@"<([0-9]+)>(.*?) < /$1>"
```

but it doesn't work.
how could i refer to the first group?

source text:

```
"Method()<0>int x = 0; while(x < 10)<1>echo(x)< /1>< /0>"
```

Comment: So, what you are looking for is the first number inside the angle brackets?  And then you are also capturing the rest of the string?  It would help if in your question you also included the exact text from your souce that you wish to capture.

Comment: please refer to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ... it's not xml, but it's similar. The guy makes a valid point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be `\1`, and watch for spaces.
See also: [.Net Regex Backreferencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Comment: I don't think `0` is a legal tag name for XML, so an XML parser will probably complain.

Comment: Even if regex works in this case, do read up on why true regex in general fails to parse XML files.

Comment: @strager - Good point, I didn't see these until I edited the question `:P`

Comment: @strager it isn't a tag name it's a value in the node

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan, I'm well aware of this.  @msarchet, Pardon?  I'm not sure what you're saying.